# Multiple Controllers in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have one site and the controller is a name of the user like `/John/NewPage`, same thing for Mary.

How can I do this without having to create a controller for each new user?

Thks

Comment: Take a look at [MVC Routing](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/older-versions/controllers-and-routing/asp-net-mvc-routing-overview-cs)

Comment: You'll want to use routing like the others are saying. You will wind up using the same controller for every user, but you'll be able to achieve your desired URLs. Then, just use the username from the URL to lookup data from your db and you are set.

Answer (score 1):

Look into custom routing. Something like:

```
    context.MapRoute(
        "User_default", // Route name
        "{userName}/{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
        new { id = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
    )
```

But you will have to take care of forming these url's yourself.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this. Define a controller named something like "UserController" then use custom routes so that it isn't necessary to have "UserController" in the URL:

```
context.MapRoute(
    "User_Route", // Route name
    "{userName}/{action}", // URL with parameters
    new { 
      controller = "UserController",
      action = "NewPage"
    } // Parameter defaults
);
```

With that setup, the "/Mary/NewPage" URL would call UserController.NewPage("Mary"), "/John/EditPage" would call UserController.EditPage("John"), and just "/Jane" would call UserController.NewPage("Jane").

You would also need to define routes for different controllers above that route so they would get called first. For example:

```
context.MapRoute(
    "SomeOther_Route", // Route name
    "SomeOtherController/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
    new { 
      controller = "SomeOtherController"
    } // Parameter defaults
);
```

The above URLs will still work, but now this URL "/SomeOtherController/DefinedAction/12" will call something like SomeOtherController.DefinedAction(12).